# Catch model event in middleware - Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I am trying to log data on each request of the application. If a user saves data for a particular model, i am trying to save the original data in a `revisions` table which is associated to an `activity_logs` table.

I have tried using model events to capture the data as follow:

```
class BaseModel extends Model
{
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::saving(function($model){
            $revision = new Revision;
            $revision->table_name = $model->getTable();
            $revision->row_id = $model->id;
            $revision->data = json_encode($model->getDirty());
            $revision->save();

            $log = ActivityLog::find(Session::pull('activity_log_id'));
            $log->revision_id = $revision->id;
            $log->save();
        });
    }
}
```

However, It seems that the model event is being fired before the middleware is instantiated so although the revision is being saved, it is being saved in the previous `GET` request instead of the new `PUT` request.

An example of the `activity_logs` is below:
[image: Example of activity logs]
Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT: Update to include tracking middleware code:**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Handle the next response and check tracking cookie
        if($request->hasCookie('session_tracking')) {
            $cookie_id    = Cookie::get('session_tracking');
            $next_request = $next($request);
        } else {
            $cookie_id    = Uuid::generate()->string;
            $next_request = $next($request)->withCookie(cookie('session_tracking', $cookie_id));
        }

        // Get user agent data
        $agent = new Agent();
        $exception = $next_request->exception;

        // Store associated log data
        $path    = $this->storePaths($request);
        $browser = $this->storeBrowser($agent);
        $os      = $this->storeOS($agent);
        $device  = $this->storeDevice($agent);
        $error   = $this->storeError($exception);

        // Store the collated log
        $activitylog = $this->storeLog($path, $browser, $os, $device, $agent, $request, $cookie_id, $error);

        Session::put('activity_log_id', $activitylog->id);

        return $next_request;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code where the `save` method is called? Was wondering if the model save is called before the middleware where you set the activity log id value in session

Comment: I have now updated my question to include the middleware code where the `activity_log_id` is being placed in the session

Comment: On which middleware is this `handle()` method?

Comment: The handle method is on the `Tracker` route middleware.

Comment: Where are you saving models in the code? Is it the store functions? If yes, you can see that you're calling the save method before setting the session variable for activity log id

Comment: When the save method is called it doesn't have the activity log id but in the saving event, you are trying to pull the Id from the session

Comment: I am saving the models in the store functions in the controller. How can i go about re-structuring this so that the save method is called after the middleware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running the controller before you are creating the new activitylog record.

If you move

```
            $next_request = $next($request);
```

to after you've created the log record then the new log record will be created before the models save method is executed.